# Validations on adaptive forms fields after submit click in bot framework v 4

Tags: c#, validation, server, frameworks, bots

how to implement validations on adaptive forms fields after submit click in Microsoft bot framework v 4 using c# at server side? also give answer for client side as well ? 
Client side and server side validations for adaptive cards using C#

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary model for AdaptiveCard response Json and add below in ActivityHandler

```
bool hasNotEmptyValues = <AdaptiveCardReturnJsonModel>.FromJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnContext.Activity.Value)).Any(pair => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pair.Value) && pair.Value.Any());
        if (!hasNotEmptyValues)
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Fill all the required values before submitting.");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this ?